# How to save photos to disk taken with imageio

Tags: python, python-imageio

This is a simple program that takes a photo from webcam. I want to know how to save the file to disk.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import imageio as iio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

camera = iio.get_reader("<video0>")
screenshot = camera.get_data(0)
camera.close()

plt.imshow(im)
```

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-and-saving-images-in-python-ba5a1f5058fb
does this help

Comment: Please Google before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mimsave function to save images. For example:

```
imageio.mimsave(filename, images)
```